# dnsmasq unrecognized command

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I'm attempting to run a script which calls service dnsmasq restart

```
service dnsmasq restart
dnsmasq: unrecognized service
```

No matter what I call for dnsmasq, it gives me the "unrecognized service" error.

Also if I type dnsmasq restart I get

```
dnsmasq restart
dnsmasq: junk found in command line
```

I have tried autoremoving and reinstalling dnsmasq.  I've googled both responses, and not finding any fixes.  Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: it is most probably because dnsmasq isn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a problem with the package `dns-root-data`. DNSmasq shouldn't require it, but it is requiring it. Follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get purge dnsmasq
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Don't forget to re-insert your configuration (if any) into `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

[Reference](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=860064)

---

**If that didn't work**, try this (works at least on Debian 9 and Raspian)

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/dnsmasq
```

Where it reads

```
if [ -f $ROOT_DS ]; then
```

Comment out the next line (add # to the beginning of the line) and put this one below it

```
`DNSMASQ_OPTS="$DNSMASQ_OPTS `mawk -- '{ printf " --trust-anchor=.,%d,%d,%d,%s", $5, $6, $7, $8 }' $ROOT_DS`"`
```

The structure of `/usr/share/dns/root.ds` was changed. The fields used to be separated only by spaces, now they are separated by tabs (\t)

[Reference](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=860274;msg=10)